# How can I loop through elements and not show previous element if next element is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to loop through labels and textareas to look like this:

```
<div className="AppBodyMain">
            <span class="an_span_seletion_text">{selection}</span>
            <div className="App-Body-Note-TextArea" id="app_body_note_ta"> 
                <div className="App-Body-Template-Selector">
                    <select id="templateselector" onChange={renderYourText}>
                    <option>Select Template</option>
                    <option value="Printer">Printer</option>
                    <option value="Scanner">Scanner</option>
                    <option value="Robot">Robot</option>
                    <option value="Pricing Calls">Pricing Calls</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div className="who_main_div" id="who_main_div">
                    <label class="an_label_who non-ta label" id="an_label_who">Who:</label>
                    <textarea className="an_ta_who" class="an_ta_who thin_ta textarea" id="autonote_ta_who" onKeyPress={AppPreventDefault}></textarea>
                </div>
                <div className="an_appTemplate_selection_section" id="an_appTemplate_selection_section">
                </div>
                <div className="note_main_div">
                    <label class="an_label_note non-ta label" id="an_label_note">Note:</label>
                    <textarea class="an_ta_note thick_ta textarea" onChange={updateNoteTA} className="an_ta_note" id="autonote_ta_note" onKeyPress={PreventDefault_Note}></textarea>
                </div>
                <div className="note_list_container">
                    <ul id="note_list_holder">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Looping through AppBodyMain I want to be able to grab all labels & textareas where textareas are not empty. If a textarea is empty. Don't add the textarea or it's label.

**There is not supposed to be a line break after 'who:' or 'Note:'. Stackoverflow wouldn't let me adjust it.**

Who:
Bob

Note:
I am a note.

If 'who' textarea is empty I want to not include the label above it. So the empty 'who' textarea would look like this:

Note:
I am a note.

I have another div in there that auto generates other labels and textareas when you select something using ReactJS. I can successfully grab all labels/textareas and show them, but when something is emtpy I can't figure out how to not show the label/textarea element. The textarea element is already not visible or showing, but the Label does like this:

**There is not supposed to be a line break after 'who:' or 'Note:'. Stackoverflow wouldn't let me adjust it.**

Who:
Note:
I am a note.

**Instead I need this**

Note:

I am a note

**Here is the source** If you need more let me know.

```js
// import React, {useState} from 'react'
import AppPreventDefault from '../Utilities/AppPreventDefault'
import Printer from '../templates/Printer'
import Scanner from '../templates/Scanner'
import PricingCalls from '../templates/PricingCalls'
import Robot from '../templates/Robot'
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const AppBody = () => {

    

    // function for adding note by pressing enter 
    const PreventDefault_Note = (e) => {
        console.log('Note Prevent Default')
        // console.log(e)
        if(e.charCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault()
            add_note();
        }
    }

    const updateNoteTA = () => {
        var ta = document.getElementById("autonote_ta_note")
        let numberOfLineBreaks = (ta.value.match(/\r\n/g) || []).length;
        ta.style.height = "0px"
        ta.style.height = ((10 + ta.scrollHeight + numberOfLineBreaks * 20 + 12 + 2) + "px")
    }
    
    const renderYourText = (e) => {
        var selected = document.getElementById('templateselector')
        var note = document.getElementById('autonote_ta_note')

        setTemplateSelection(selected)

        const resetSelection = (selected) => {
            selected.selectedIndex = 0
        }

        if(selected.value === "Printer"){
            InsertExtraPrinterElements()
            console.log(selected.value)
            resetSelection(selected)
            updateNoteTA()
        }

        if(selected.value === "Scanner"){
            RemoveExtraElements()
            InsertExtraScannerElements()
            console.log(selected.value)
            resetSelection(selected)
            updateNoteTA()
        }

        if(selected.value === "Robot"){
            RemoveExtraElements()
            InsertExtraRobotElements()
            console.log(selected.value)
            resetSelection(selected)
            updateNoteTA()
        }

        if(selected.value === "Pricing Calls"){
            RemoveExtraElements()
            // add text to textarea
            note.value = PricingCalls
            // log selected
            console.log(selected.value)
            // resetSelection
            resetSelection(selected)
            // set value of Pricing Call text to the textarea value
            var value = note.value
            // Add note and clear the textarea value
            add_note(value)
            // reset selection
            updateNoteTA()
        }
    }

    const InsertExtraPrinterElements = () => {
        const printerElement = <Printer/>
        ReactDOM.render(printerElement, document.getElementById('an_appTemplate_selection_section'));
    }

    const InsertExtraScannerElements = () => {
        const printerElement = <Scanner/>
        ReactDOM.render(printerElement, document.getElementById('an_appTemplate_selection_section'));
    }

    const InsertExtraRobotElements = () => {
        const printerElement = <Robot/>
        ReactDOM.render(printerElement, document.getElementById('an_appTemplate_selection_section'));
    }

    const RemoveExtraElements = () => {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('an_appTemplate_selection_section'));
    }
    
    const add_note = () => {
    
        // create base parent variables
        var parent = document.getElementById("note_list_holder");
        var main_elements = document.querySelectorAll('#AppBody label,textarea')
        var main_elements_tas = document.querySelectorAll('#AppBody textarea')  
        var note = document.createElement('span');
        //var note_container_list_main = document.createElement('div');
        //note_container_list_main.classList.add('note_container_list_main');
        var note_container_div = document.createElement('div');
        var notes = [];
        
        // push the notation text into an array
        notes.push(note);
    
        // loop over each notation to create a note_container_div
        // complete with proper formatting and timestamp
        notes.forEach(function(note){
            // create elements 
            var note_li = document.createElement('li');
            //note_li.classList.add('an_note_list_ul_li')
            var topLine = document.createElement('span');
            //topLine.classList.add('an_note_container_topLine')
            var bottomLine = document.createElement('span');    
            
            var topL = document.createTextNode('======================\n\n');
            var botL = document.createTextNode('======================');

            //console.log(main_elements)

            Array.prototype.slice.call(main_elements).forEach(function(area){
                
                var labeltemp = area.textContent
                var textareatemp = area.value
                var textarea_TextNode = document.createTextNode(`${textareatemp}\n\n`);
                var label_TextNode = document.createTextNode(`${labeltemp}\n`);
                // var l = "--------------------"
                // Console log the value
                if(area.value === "" || area.tagName === "LABEL"){
                    console.log('textarea is undefined or empty')
                }else{
                    console.log(`${labeltemp}`);
                    console.log(`${textareatemp}`)
                    if(area.value){
                        note.appendChild(label_TextNode);
                        note.appendChild(textarea_TextNode)
                    }
                }
                
            });
            
            Array.prototype.slice.call(main_elements_tas).forEach(function(area){
                if(area){
                    area.value = ""
                }
            })


            topLine.appendChild(topL);
            bottomLine.appendChild(botL);
            note_container_div.appendChild(topLine);
            note_container_div.appendChild(note);
            note_container_div.appendChild(bottomLine);
            // adding classes to elements
            note_container_div.classList.add('note_container_div');
    
            // appending note_container_div to note_li
            note_li.appendChild(note_container_div); 
        
            // inserting note_li into parent list at the top
            parent.insertBefore(note_li, parent.childNodes[0]);
    
        });
    
        // create variable that holds the entire note_container_div text
        const note_container_text = note_container_div.innerText
        
        // Copy the div to clipboard
        function listener(e) {
            e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", note_container_text);
            e.preventDefault();
        } 
        document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
    
        // focus on who
        document.getElementById('autonote_ta_who').focus(); 
        
    }

    const [selection, setSelection] = useState('Select Template')

    const setTemplateSelection = (e) => {
        var select = document.getElementById('templateselector')
        setSelection(select.value)
        //console.log(select.value)
    }

    return(
        <div className="AppBody" id="AppBody">
            <div className="AppBodyMain">
                <span class="an_span_seletion_text">{selection}</span>
                <div className="App-Body-Note-TextArea" id="app_body_note_ta"> 
                    <div className="App-Body-Template-Selector">
                        <select id="templateselector" onChange={renderYourText}>
                        <option>Select Template</option>
                        <option value="Printer">Printer</option>
                        <option value="Scanner">Scanner</option>
                        <option value="Robot">Robot</option>
                        <option value="Pricing Calls">Pricing Calls</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="who_main_div" id="who_main_div">
                        <label class="an_label_who non-ta label" id="an_label_who">Who:</label>
                        <textarea className="an_ta_who" class="an_ta_who thin_ta textarea" id="autonote_ta_who" onKeyPress={AppPreventDefault}></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="an_appTemplate_selection_section" id="an_appTemplate_selection_section">
                    </div>
                    <div className="note_main_div">
                        <label class="an_label_note non-ta label" id="an_label_note">Note:</label>
                        <textarea class="an_ta_note thick_ta textarea" onChange={updateNoteTA} className="an_ta_note" id="autonote_ta_note" onKeyPress={PreventDefault_Note}></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="note_list_container">
                        <ul id="note_list_holder">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }




    export default AppBody
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I always recommend new users review [ask] for tips on forming their questions.  It is customary to include what attempts you have made in order to better assist the community to help you.  Especially since this is a React project, it would be critical context for visitors to this post.  Can you include your previous attempts and explain how they have fallen short?  If it is possible to do this in a [mcve] snippet, all the better.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: I added my source code that is the attempt I've tried so far if that is what is being asked for.

Comment: I hope you understand how react works. You don't need all these event emitters and listeners to make this work. I suggest you go over the concepts of react once more, and for your question you can show/hide things easily with JSX, where you can put certain tags inside conditions. https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the question at hand is not really pertinent to the fact that the code you've shown is basically not idiomatic React, and in fact contains many React antipatterns.  It might be smart to try to complete some React tutorials and walkthroughs to get a better sense of how React is intended to be used; otherwise, you're looking at major maintainability issues down the line.  Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate everyone's comments, but aside from the noob references (which I am not mad) is it possible to either show a small working example or a reference? I'll look into the resources provided, but I still don't believe my question was answered.